# i want to get data from by selecting the class and print it in a console using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
      <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

      <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

      <button type="submit" onclick=" doFunction()">Login</button>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>

    <script>
    function doFunction(){
    var data = $('.container').serializeArray();//this will convert into array
    console.log(typeof data)//print the type of data
    console.log(data);//print the data
}
</script>
</body>
```

I want to select the class by id and see data in the console to check whether data is being processed correctly or not. I am getting length=0 when printing the data.

**My output:**

```
object
blabla.html:25 []
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
blabla.html:27 
string
```

Comment: Can you please be specific about the variables and the motive of your raised question? Its difficult to understand with the given logic and the information provided about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `serializeArray()` method is intended to be called on `form` elements, not `div`. As such you should hook your logic to the `submit` event of a parent form, not the `click` of a button, and certainly not using an `on*` event attribute. Try this:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).serializeArray();

  console.log(typeof data) //print the type of data
  console.log(data); //print the data
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="/foo">
  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> 
      Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

You need to use `form` to serilize the inputs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <form id="loginform" name="test" method="post">     

        <div class="container">
              <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

              <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

              <button type="submit" onclick=" doFunction()">Login</button>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
              </label>
        </div>
      </form>
    <script>
    function doFunction(){
        var data = $('#loginform').serializeArray();//this will convert into array
        console.log(typeof data)//print the type of data
        console.log(data);//print the data
        return false;
    }
</script>
</body>
```